# Orientation of manifold given by external normal field

Tags: manifolds

> > Consider the unit sphere $S^1$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is a 1-dimensional manifold. And an orientation $\sigma$ of $S^1$ is given by the orientated atlas $\left\{\phi_1,\phi_2\right\}$ with the maps
> >     $$
> > \phi_1\colon (-\pi,\pi)\to S^1\setminus (-1,0), t\mapsto (\cos t,\sin t)\\
> > \phi_2\colon (0,2\pi)\to S^1\setminus (1,0), t\mapsto (\cos t,\sin t)
> > $$
> >     Moreover an orientation of $S^1$ is given by the external normal field
> >     $$
> > \nu\colon S^1\to\mathbb{R}^2.
> > $$
> >     Show that the orientation given by the external normal field is identical with the orientation $\sigma$ above.

Do I have to show that the external normal field $\nu$ is positive orientated related to $\sigma$? Or something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to show that, if you pick a point $p\in S^{1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then  $\nu(p),v(p)$ is positively oriented in $T_{p}\mathbb{R}^2$, where $v(p)$ is the oriented basis for $T_{p}S^{1}$ you get from the atlas $\{\phi_1,\phi_2\}$. Is this what you meant by "the external normal field $\nu$ is positive oriented related to $\sigma$"?

Comment: I guess you mean exactly what I meant: Does $S^1$ have an orientation $\sigma$, then the external normal field $\nu$ is called positive orientated related to $\sigma$" if for any $a\in S^1$ the following condition is fullfilled: Let $(w_1)$ be a positive orientated basis of $T_a S^1$, then $(\nu(a),w_1)$ is a positive orientated basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $det(\nu(a),w_1) > 0$.  --- And now I wanted to use the positive orientated map $\phi_1$ and the positive orientated basis $\left(\frac{\partial\phi_1(c)}{\partial t}\right)$, $a:=\phi_1(c), c\in (-\pi,\pi)$ to show that.

Comment: Is this what I have to show?

Comment: I think we agree on what we're saying, so you have my vote.

Comment: I think it's not that difficult: Consider any $\phi_1(c)=:a\in S^1$, $c\in (-\pi,\pi)$. $\phi_1$ is a positive orientated map and $\left(\frac{\partial\phi_1(c)}{\partial t}\right)$ is a positve orientated basis of $T_aS^1$. Because of $\frac{\partial\phi_1(c)}{\partial t}=(-\sin c,\cos c)$ it is $det\left(\nu(a),\frac{\partial\phi_1(c)}{\partial t}\right)=det(a,(-\sin c,\cos c))=det((\cos c,\sin c),(-\sin c,\cos c))=1 > 0$ and that's what I wanted to show. --- That's it?

Comment: I think that's it.